# Intercepting *.aspx

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to intercept every aspx requests. The interception works, but the page stay blank. What am I missing ?

```
namespace WebSite
{
    public class Class1 : IHttpHandler
    {
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {

        }
    }
}

<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="SampleHandler" verb="*"
        path="*.aspx"
        type="WebSite.Class1, WebSite"
        resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: You're missing some accepted answers in your other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're intercepting the page request, then you're not doing anything with it. If you expect to see some sort of output, you have to perform some kind of manipulation to the HttpContext being passed in. Below are a couple of articles that might be decent reading when dealing with the HttpContext. In a nutshell, if you expect to see a response, you have to generate something to it.

http://odetocode.com/Articles/112.aspx
[What is the difference between HttpContext.Current.Response and Page.Response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676503/what-is-the-difference-between-httpcontext-current-response-and-page-response)
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/desaijm/asp.netposturl11282005005516am/asp.netposturl.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You're not really intercepting them. That's more like hijacking them. Every *.aspx request will go to this handler and not the actual *.aspx page. A more suitable method would be for you to look in the `Application_BeginRequest` handler in `global.asax`.

Answer (score 0):

I used the IhttpHandler interface to handle my image return.

The IHttpHandlerFactory is what I use to handle Page interception:

```
public class HttpCMSHandlerFactory : IHttpHandlerFactory
{
    // collects page name requested
    string pageName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(context.Request.PhysicalPath);
    // Add the page name to the context
    context.Items.Add("PageName", pageName);
    // I can still check if the page physically exists else pass on to my CMS handler: CMSPage.aspx
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(context.Request.MapPath(context.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath));
    if (fi.Exists == false)
    {
        // if page doesnt exist context info is passed on to CMSPage to handle copy
        return PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance(string.Concat(context.Request.ApplicationPath, "/CMSPage.aspx"), url, context);
    }
    else
    {
        // if page exist physical page is returned
        return PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance(context.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath, fi.FullName, context);
    }
}
```

[check out my previous post on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678608/using-httphandlerfactory-to-render-cms-and-physical-pages)